# How to get all rows of table (or dataset) object A that match some row of table (or dataset) object B?

Tags: matlab

Let `A` and `B` be two `table` (or `dataset`) objects having a few factor variables `K1, K2, ..., Kn` in common.  I'll call these *n* factors **key factors**.  Also, I'll say that a row of `A` and a row of `B` **match** iff they match at these key factors, i.e. iff `A.K1 == B.K1 & A.K2 == B.K2 & ... & A.Kn == B.Kn`.

(I give an example of the above, with code, at the end of this post.)

> I'm looking for an *efficient* way to extract all the rows of `A` that "match" one<sup>1</sup> row of `B`.

(More precisely, I want to generate a new table `C` consisting of all the rows of `A` that "match" one row of `B`.)

---

Is there an efficient way to do this?  (I'm trying to avoid `for`-Loop Hell here, or any solution that depends on knowing, say, the number of key factors, etc., since I want to use this in code that does not know much about `A` and `B` until runtime.)

I tried `intersect(A, B)`, but it fails with the error:

```
>> keyfactors = intersect(A.Properties.VarNames, B.Properties.VarNames);
>> intersect(A, B, keyfactors)
Error using table/intersect (line 41)
A and B must contain the same variables.
```

The only other strategy I can come up with (though I don't yet know how to implement it) is to somehow *synthesize* a function on-the-fly based on the information encoded in `B`.  For example, given an indexing table `B` like this

```
B = cell2table({
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds';
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades';
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts'
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               {'Parity', 'TrafficLight', 'Suit'});
```

...somehow programmatically generate a function like

```
fn = @(c) any([all([strcmp(c(:, 1), 'even'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 2), 'red'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 3), 'diamonds')], 2), ...
               all([strcmp(c(:, 1), 'odd'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 2), 'yellow'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 3), 'spades')], 2), ...
               all([strcmp(c(:, 1), 'odd'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 2), 'green'), ...
                    strcmp(c(:, 3), 'hearts')], 2)], 2);
```

...that could then be used in an expression like this:

```
Ac = table2cell(A);
C = cell2table(Ac(fn(Ac), :), ...
               'VariableNames', B.Properties.VariableNames);
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to programmatically synthesize a function like `fn` above without resorting to the (strongly deprecated) use of `eval`.

---

Here are examples of the kinds of `A` and `B` tables I'm thinking of.  (For those who don't have a version of MATLAB that supports the (rather new) `table` objects, the code below should work if the strings "table" and "VariableNames" are replaced with the strings "dataset" and "VarNames", respectively.)

```
% "data" table
A = cell2table({
                'even', 'red', 'spades', 38, 0.9837;
                'even', 'red', 'hearts', 19, 0.5695;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 89, 0.2629;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 98, 0.3578;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 92, 0.2596;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.5751;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 77, 0.6318;
                'even', 'yellow', 'clubs', 22, 0.6917;
                'even', 'green', 'spades', 35, 0.6674;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 67, 0.7896;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 49, 0.5025;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 64, 0.5318;
                'odd', 'red', 'spades', 22, 0.5587;
                'odd', 'red', 'hearts', 51, 0.9122;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 74, 0.3343;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.2911;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 33, 0.2653;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 38, 0.2549;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 1, 0.2064;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 25, 0.8257;
                'odd', 'green', 'spades', 64, 0.4348;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 59, 0.8644;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 4, 0.6374;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 11, 0.3354
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               {'Parity', 'TrafficLight', 'Suit', 'order', 'prevalence'});

% "indexing" table
B = cell2table({
                'i', 'even', 'red', 'diamonds';
                'ii', 'odd', 'yellow', 'spades';
                'iii', 'odd', 'green', 'hearts'
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               [{'class'} A.Properties.VariableNames(1:3)]);

keyfactors = intersect(B.Properties.VariableNames, ...
                       A.Properties.VariableNames, ...
                       'stable');

% this fails:
% intersect(A, B, keyfactors);

% desired subtable would look like this one
C = cell2table({
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 89, 0.2629;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 98, 0.3578;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 92, 0.2596;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.5751;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 77, 0.6318;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 33, 0.2653;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 38, 0.2549;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 59, 0.8644;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 4, 0.6374;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 11, 0.3354
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               {'Parity', 'TrafficLight', 'Suit', 'order', 'prevalence'});
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> One may safely assume that, in `B`, any combination of values (aka "levels") for the key factors would appear *at most once*.  This would usually *not* be true for `A`.  In practice, `A` would contain real data, while `B` would be "synthetic" (i.e. constructed specifically for the operation described here), and would have fewer variables and *much* fewer rows than `A` does.  One may therefore think of `B` as an "indexing table" for `A`.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns what you want, but I don't know if it works generally so you'll need to test:

```
[~,iB,iA] = intersect(B.Properties.VariableNames, ...
                      A.Properties.VariableNames, ...
                      'stable');
C = A(ismember(A(:,iA),intersect(A(:,iA),B(:,iB),'stable')),:)
```

Part of the problem is that `table/intersect` only returns the first occurrence when rows a re repeated. I use `table/ismember` to produce logical indices to get around this.

Comment: Beautiful!  I'm blown away by your solution, actually.  Even though I've been writing code forever, I still cannot "think in MATLAB".  I'm not even close, in fact, judging by how I'm still *completely* blindsided by code like your snippet above.

Comment: @kjo: Thanks. It was a fun little problem and your examples were helpful. If you want speed however, you might try what you refer to as "`for` loop hell." What you seem to be doing might be quite easily done with some `for` loops and you might be surprised at the performance. `intersect` and company are based on numerous `for` loops under the hood after all (`ismember` uses a fast C function) and are doing much more than you actually need.